# Accessing the width of a peak using findpeaks (signal package)

Tags: octave

I am using the [findpeaks function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/findpeaks.html) located in the signal package and I am struggling to obtain the width of the detected peak.

From looking at the documentation it says:

> "roots"
>   The abscissa values (in index units) at which the parabola fitted to each of the returned peaks crosses the "baseline" value. The width of the peak is calculated by diff(roots).
>
> This function accepts property-value pair given in the list below...

I have obtained the struct from findpeaks and this is my output:

```
ans =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    parabol =

      scalar structure containing the fields:

        x =

           91
           95
    pp =

      -3.1387e+004  5.8853e+006  -1.6238e+008


height =   1.1352e+008
baseline =   6.6495e+007
roots =

   132.461    55.050
```

So i believe that the `roots` object provides me the width of the peak, but how do I output this data, into say another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the documentation, you have to call `findpeaks` with 3 output arguments:

[pks, loc, extra] = findpeaks( ...)

The abscissa values (in index units) of the first peak is in the variable `extra.roots(1,:)` so the width is:

```
width = extra.roots(1,1) - extra.roots(1,2)
```

Here is an example:

```
t = 2*pi*linspace(0,1,1024)';
y = sin(3.14*t) + 0.5*cos(6.09*t) + 0.1*sin(10.11*t+1/6) + 0.1*sin(15.3*t+1/3);
figure,plot(data1)
hold on
plot(extra.roots(1,:),[0,0],'r','linewidth',10)
```

The example shows the width of the 1st peak as a red strip on the x-axis.

If you want to know the width in the units of the variable `t` then you should scale it like this:

```
width = (extra.roots(1,1) - extra.roots(1,2)) * (t(2)-t(1))
```

I hope this helps.